# Access website on laptop localhost over USB, from android (NO WiFi)

Tags: android, adb

I have Firefox on the laptop using Debian, Firefox on the phone (Android-not rooted), I want to **use the USB** to access the wordpress website I have locally on the laptop. 
I want to be able to type in Firefox on android: http://localhost/mywebsite , or static-IP/mywebsite.

I can see my device connected when I type in terminal: adb devices. I tried 127.0.0.1, I tried 10.0.2.2, I'm reading all kind of tips, but nothing clear using **ONLY USB** connection (no wifi or wired).

On Chrome seems to be very simple with (reverse) port forwarding: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=de#port-forwarding

Comment: How are connected to laptop from your phone via usb ? which feature are you using usb tethering or something?

Comment: @VishavjeetSingh I don't know exactly what feature. I plug the USB, I enable the Abdroid Debugging and ADB over network on my phone and I check in the terminal on my laptop to see if it's connected (which it is): adb devices. It's working over wifi, but I need USB.

Comment: you can't acess websites or local webpages through adb.

Comment: it is just made to execute commands on device

Comment: @VishavjeetSingh I mentioned before the steps I take to connect the phone to the laptop. In the first post I described what my problem is and what I need. I just want to type in Firefox on Android: localhost(:port)/mywebsite, just as I do on the  laptop.  Chrome seems to do it easily. It doesn't work at the moment in my environment, which I described in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, here are the steps I found it work (*no wifi connection*):

Connect phone to laptop using USB

1. On the phone enable in:

a) Developer Options: "Android debugging" and "ADB over network"

b) Settings > ...More > Tethering > USB tethering

2. On the laptop:

a) find your new ip in terminal with the command: `ip addr` (should be something like: 192.168.xx.x). Then go back to the phone's browser and visit your website at: 192.168.xx.x/mywebsite

b) make sure you local server is running

c) in terminal verify if your phone is connected by typing: `adb devices`

d) forward the port you find in the phone at "ADB over network" (mine is 5555), by typing the command: `adb forward tcp:5555 localfilesystem:/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/firefox-debugger-socket`

e) in Firefox go to Developer > Connect and type in "host" the numbers before the colon and in "port", the ones after the colon (mine: 0.0.0.0:5555). Then hit "Connect" and go to the browser on the phone to hit OK for accepting the connection